# C# - Can you loop through types separately in a generic list?

Tags: c#, foreach, generic-list

I have 3 different classes, a generic "entity" class, and then two classes that inherit this, a bullet class and an enemy class.

I then have a list of the entity class, with the bullets and enemies in the list, and a lot of the places I treat these the same. However, some times, I want to loop through just one of the classes, and not the other, e.g. Loop through each bullet, but not the enemies. Is there any way to do this?

I tried

```
foreach (Bullet tempBullet in entities)
```

But I get the error

> Unable to cast object of type 'Enemy' to type 'Bullet'.

Anyone know if this is possible, or do I have to use seperate lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably use a little Linq:

```
foreach (var bullet in entities.OfType<Bullet>())
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 2:

```
foreach (Entity ent in entities) {
    Enemy e = ent as Enemy;
    Bullet b = ent as Bullet;

    if (e != null) {
        // process enemy
    }
    else if (b != null) {
        // process bullet
    }
}
```

or, using linq (and `entities` is an object that inherits `IEnumerable<T>`):

```
foreach (Bullet bullet in entities.OfType<Bullet>()) {
    // process bullets only
}
```

Comment: But then you're doing two casts, as you're presumably doing a `(Enemy)ent` later on.